# gettext: retrieve msgid from msgstr

Tags: php, gettext

Is it possible to retrieve the msgid from a given msgstr without messing around with the po-files?

Comment: If it could be done with a command line that'd be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse lookup? Not with the native PHP gettext extension. But you can use `gettext.php` from [upgradephp](http://upgradephp.berlios.de/). Specifically look for `gettext___load_mo($fn,"domain")`. It fills up a global `$_GETTEXT` array from the raw .mo data, and you could use `array_flip($_GETTEXT["domain"])` to receive a msgstr->msgid mapping.